# How can we write a M3u file in downloads folder in Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, storage-access-framework

I am trying to save an m3u file in Downloads folder in Android 11

this is the code I am referring to

[Here](https://github.com/kabouzeid/Phonograph/blob/d156872cc5ac7f5f295b5fad361974c5fea45631/app/src/main/java/com/kabouzeid/gramophone/helper/M3UWriter.java)

specially this partof the code

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

            bw.write(HEADER);
            for (Song song : songs) {
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(ENTRY + song.duration + DURATION_SEPARATOR + song.artistName + " - " + song.title);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(song.data);
            }

            bw.close();
```

I want to save the file to Downloads folder due to the restrictions in Android 11

with this code

```
 ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "PlayListOwn");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/my-custom-type");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

Please provide solution in **Java** not kotlin Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem?  And if your code runs on 10- it should run on 11+ too.

Comment: I have changed the question , how can we use this.

Comment: What is the problem? Please post full code. We dont see you using that uri.

Comment: We need to use `ContentResolver resolver` I want to know how can we use this code to write a  new m3u file.

Comment: In the same way as under Android 10 and lower. And about in the same way as any other file.  And you still didnt tell the problem. And you do no need to use the media store.